# Indicator array of whether value is contained in another numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I code which items in array 1 are contained within array 2, and append a row reflecting this (1 = it is contained, 0 = it is not:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,10,12,13])

array2 = np.array([4,6,3,5,0])
```

**Expected Result:**

```
np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,10,12,13],
           [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]])
```

Comment: use `np.isin()` method

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and cast the result to integer, the solution is within the previous answer :)

```
np.vstack([array1, np.isin(array1, array2).view('i1')])
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 10, 12, 13],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0]])
```